# MSSQL Characters not appearing

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, multilingual, cultureinfo

So, I'm storing Norweigan characters in an MSSQL table, using nvarchar.

One some pages when I pull these back out in ASP, they display fine...

*5 tips som kan hjelpe deg med måltidsplanlegging*

But on other pages it's displaying as...

*5 tips som kan hjelpe deg med mÃ¥ltidsplanlegging*

The recordset is made exactly the same way, the files are on the same server, and even on the same site. The only real difference is that where it displays correctly, the rest of the page is in English, but where the rest of the page is in Norweigan it displays with the odd characters.

In the database itself it's actually stored as **mÃ¥ltidsplanlegging**, but then on some pages displays correctly as **måltidsplanlegging**.

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?

Comment: looks like this is an ASP.NET question. please use tags properly.

Comment: It's in classic ASP actually rather than .net.

Comment: this question about php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through but almost everything could be applied to classic asp

Comment: @Lashane what is the point in posting a PHP link for an Classic ASP encoding problem? There not even remotely similar but there are plenty of Classic ASP questions / answers on the subject.

Comment: @Lankymart at least 75% of advises from this answer can be applied to classic asp

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to the top of your page:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001    
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```